# Xamarin "generator.exe" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The filename or extension is too long

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin project on visual studio 2019 version 16.7.1. When I am building the project "The specified task executable "generator.exe" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The filename or extension is too long" error is throwing. I have no code errors and for others in the team it is building and I am the newest team member. I recently updated visual studio to the latest version.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/path-too-long-exception

Comment: @vin Already tried. not working

Comment: did you try this as well? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181313/unhandled-exception-system-componentmodel-win32exception-0x80004005

Comment: I downgrade visual studio to 16.6.5 and now project is building. Did not get the chance the try above way @vin.